# Resharper breaks Edit.FindAllReferences (not just the shortcut)

Tags: resharper, keyboard-shortcuts

I install ReSharperSetup.7.1.1000.900.msi. This broke Edit.FindAllReferences in Visual Studio 2008.

I don't mean that it broke Shift-F12, which is the usual VS2008 shortcut to Edit.FindAllReferences, I mean that it broke Edit.FindAllReferences itself.

I know this because Edit.FindAllReferences was bound to Ctrl+K,R and pressing this resulted in a tooltip saying “Usages of ‘[whatever]’ were not found”.

I uninstalled Resharper and then Edit.FindAllReferences works again.

I Googled for about an hour to try to fix this but no solution works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed by JetBrains:

> Thank you for contacting us.
>
> There is a known issue - http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-336714
>
> and seems like the issue was fixed here -
>   http://download-ln.jetbrains.com/resharper/ReSharperSetup.7.1.1000.1094.msi.
>
> Please let me know about the result.
>
> We are sorry for the inconvenience.
>
> Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Usages of '[whatever]' is R#'s "Find Usages" feature - which maps to Ctrl+K,R by default to give a better Find References. If you don't want R#'s version, then change the key mapping back to Visual Studio's default Edit.FindAll...

Comment: Resharper's find usages doesn't work either, with the same error.